# C array of functions

Tags: c, arrays, function, return

I have a problem with a series of functions. I have an array of 'return values' (i compute them through matrices) from a single function **sys** which depends on a integer variable, lets say, **j**, and I want to return them according to this **j** , i mean, if i want the equation number **j**, for example, i just write **sys(j)**
For this, i used a **for** loop but i don't know if it's well defined, because when i run my code, i don't get the right values.
 Is there a better way to have an array of functions and call them in a easy way? That would make easier to work with a function in a Runge Kutta method to solve a diff equation.

I let this part of the code here: (**c** is just the **j** integer i used to explain before)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int N=3;
double s=10.;
//float r=28.;
double b=8.0/3.0;

/ * Define functions * /
double sys(int c,double r,double y[])
{
    int l,m,n,p=0;
    double tmp;
    double t[3][3]={0};
    double j[3][3]={{-s,s,0},{r-y[2],-1,-y[0]},{y[1],y[0],-b}}; //Jacobiano
    double id[3][3] = { {y[3],y[6],y[9]} , {y[4],y[7],y[10]} , {y[5],y[8],y[11]} };
    double flat[N*(N+1)];

    // Multiplication of matrices J * Y
    for(l=0;l<N;l++)
    {
        for(m=0;m<N;m++)
        {
            for(n=0;n<N;n++)
            {
                t[l][m] += j[l][n] * id[n][m];
            }
        }
    }

    // Transpose the matrix (J * Y) -> () t
    for(l=0;l<N;l++)
    {
        for(m=l+1;m<N;m++)
        {
            tmp = t[l][m];
            t[l][m] = t[m][l];
            t[m][l] = tmp;
        }
    }

    // We flatten the array to be left in one array 
    for(l=0;l<N;l++)
    {
        for(m=0;m<N;m++)
        {
            flat[p+N] = t[l][m];
        }
    }

    flat[0] = s*(y[1]-y[0]);
    flat[1] = y[0]*(r-y[2])-y[1];
    flat[2] = y[0]*y[1]-b*y[2];

    for(l=0;l<(N*(N+1));l++)
    {
        if(c==l)
        {
            return flat[c];
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT ----------------------------------------------------------------

Ok, this is the part of the code where i use the function

```
int main(){
output = fopen("lyapcoef.dat","w");
int j,k;
int N2 = N*N;
int NN = N*(N+1);
double r;
double rmax = 29;
double t = 0;
double dt = 0.05;
double tf = 50;
double z[NN]; // Temporary matrix for RK4
double k1[N2],k2[N2],k3[N2],k4[N2];
double y[NN]; // Matrix for all variables

/* Initial conditions */

double u[N];
double phi[N][N];
double phiu[N];
double norm;
double lyap;
//Here we integrate the system using Runge-Kutta of fourth order

for(r=28;r<rmax;r++){   
    y[0]=19;
    y[1]=20;
    y[2]=50;
    for(j=N;j<NN;j++) y[j]=0;
    for(j=N;j<NN;j=j+3) y[j]=1; // Identity matrix for y from 3 to 11 
    while(t<tf){
        /* RK4 step 1 */
        for(j=0;j<NN;j++){
            k1[j] = sys(j,r,y)*dt;
            z[j] = y[j] + k1[j]*0.5;
        }
        /* RK4 step 2 */
        for(j=0;j<NN;j++){
            k2[j] = sys(j,r,z)*dt;
            z[j] = y[j] + k2[j]*0.5;
        }
        /* RK4 step 3 */
        for(j=0;j<NN;j++){
            k3[j] = sys(j,r,z)*dt;
            z[j] = y[j] + k3[j];
        }
        /* RK4 step 4 */
        for(j=0;j<NN;j++){
            k4[j] = sys(j,r,z)*dt;
        }
        /* Updating y matrix with new values */
        for(j=0;j<NN;j++){
            y[j] += (k1[j]/6.0 + k2[j]/3.0 + k3[j]/3.0 + k4[j]/6.0);
        }
        printf("%lf %lf %lf \n",y[0],y[1],y[2]);
        t += dt; 
    }
```

Comment: Please translate your comments to english before posting next time, as well as improving your code formatting.

Comment: Oh sorry, i'll consider that in my next posts. Thanks

Comment: Did you really use the letter 'l' as a loop variable? Thats nearly impossible to read or support. I would suggest ignoring the mathematical part of this problem and write a simple use-case/example of the scenario and either debug it yourself or present your question without the complexity of the real world example. There are too many unknowns about what you are asking, and the other responders are latching on to responses which may not answer the actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're actually computing all these values at the same time, what you really want is for the function to return them all together. The easiest way to do this is to pass in a pointer to an array, into which the function will write the values. Or perhaps two arrays; it looks to me as if the output of your function is (conceptually) a 3x3 matrix together with a length-3 vector.

So the declaration of `sys` would look something like this:

```
void sys(double v[3], double JYt[3][3], double r, const double y[12]);
```

where `v` would end up containing the first three elements of your `flat` and `JYt` would contain the rest. (More informative names are probably possible.)

Incidentally, the `for` loop at the end of your code is exactly equivalent to just saying `return flat[c];` except that if `c` happens not to be >=`0` and <`N*(N+1)` then control will just fall off the end of your function, which in practice means that it will return some random number that almost certainly isn't what you want.

Comment: Mm yes, but i do need the values in a single array, that's why I "flatten" the matrix in one of the last steps in the sys function. The first three `flat` are the Lorenz system, the rest are anoher diff equations that depends on the first, so that's why i need to compute all the matrices again each time i call the function

Comment: I was asking if it's well defined or if there's some error making a `for` loop with the `return` inside it. Or if there's a better way to get that same output, i just don't wanna write the 12 different equations in sepparated functions because that would make a huge runge Kutta in the `main` part of the code

Comment: If you want the outputs in a single flattened array, that's fine. (So: `void sys(double v[12], double r, const double y[12]);`.) Unless I've badly misunderstood the calling code you posted, you really truly don't need to keep calling `sys` repeatedly. For instance, in your "RK4 step 1" block, `sys` will compute the same stuff in `flat` each time. Make it print out the comments of `flat` and check if you don't believe me.

Comment: The `for` loop with a `return` inside it is pointless and inefficient and will make the function exhibit undefined behaviour if the value of `c` is out of range -- but, apart from that, there's nothing wrong with it :-). It's not illegal C or anything.

Comment: Ok, so i call the function before each step of RK4 and then just use `flat[]` in the loop? That would be much faster . Thanks, i'll try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `sys()` does an O(N<sup>3</sup>) calculation to multiply two matrices, then does a couple of O(N<sup>2</sup>) operations, and finally selects a single number to return.  Then it is called the next time and goes through most of the same processing.  It feels a tad wasteful unless (*even if?*) the matrices are really small.

The final loop in the function is a little odd, too:

```
for(l=0;l<(N*(N+1));l++)
{
    if(c==l)
    {
        return flat[c];
    }
}
```

Isn't that more simply written as:

```
return flat[c];
```

Or, perhaps:

```
if (c < N * (N+1))
    return flat[c];
else
    ...do something on disastrous error other than fall off the end of the
    ...function without returning a value as the code currently does...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are selecting an algorithm by the value of j. If that's what you're trying to describe, in C you can have an array of pointers to functions; you could use a numerical index to choose a function from the array, but you can also pass a pointer-to-a-function to another function that will call it.

That said: Judging from your code, you should keep it simple. If you want to use a number to control which code gets executed, just use an `if` or `switch` statement.

```
switch (c) {
case 0:
  /* Algorithm 0 */
  break;
case 1:
  /* Algorithm 1 */
  etc.
```

Comment: Re: "I don't see where you are selecting an algorithm by the value of j": it's at the very bottom, at the `return` statement. (The current code computes values using all three algorithms, but attempts to only *return* the value that was computed by the specified algorithm.)

Comment: Use a switch statement. For starters, you can replace the whole last loop with `return flat[c]`.

Comment: It sounds like you've confused me with the OP?

Comment: Thanks for yours answers. If i use **switch** i would have to write like 14 **case** . I wanted to avoid that, that's the reason why i used a **for** loop . The matrices should always be computed, , the important part is at the bottom, like you said, so if i call the function using j, it throws me the j value of the array flat [] . I was wondering if it was well defined